# Using PHP, how can I make a cookie expire after the browser is closed?

Tags: cookies

Using PHP, how can I make a cookie expire after the browser is closed?

Comment: This has very little to do with PHP... a cookie is a cookie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't set an expiry time. That will make it a session cookie.

This is mentioned in the documentation for the expire argument to [setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie):

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).